# Show that 2 numbers are of the same order

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

given following equation:

$x^D \leq Ax^B \leq Dx^D$

i want to show that $B \approx D$

I split the inequality into two parts.

1. $x^D \leq Ax^B$
2. $Ax^B \leq Dx^D$

I'm not sure, from the first part I can see that D is bigger than B.
but I can't prove it, I think it's simple, I'm not sure.

Comment: This very much depends on $x$ and $A$. What is known about them?

Comment: If the inequality holds for $0<x<a$ for a fixed $a>0$ then $B=D.$ Also $B=D$ if the inequality holds for  $x>b>0$ for a fixed $b.$

Comment: I don't know if it can help, but they (A, x, B ,D) are always positive and greater than one.

Comment: And also D is the smallest power that can be for this inequality